# Pressing button on record list based on conditions

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a list of records with for example status, department, amount, title  and some buttons.
If I wanted to assert for example the title I used the following code:

```
private IWebElement GetTitleElement(int actionRowNumber)
    {
        var xpath = $"//tr[@id = 'ctl00_ctl00_CPH_CPH_ActionsOverviewControl1_RadGridActions_ctl00__{actionRowNumber}']/td[9]";
        return BrowserFactory.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath));
    }
```

I am doing the same for type, status, department

And then I used a try catch method to go through each record untill I found the desired record in the system:

```
public void CheckActionxxx(ActionTypes type, Enum.Departments departments, Enum.ActionStatus actionstatus, string title)
    {
        Wait();
        var actiontype = type;
        try
        {
            for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
            {
                if (GetTitleElement(i).Text == title && GetActionTypeElement(i).Text == actiontype.ToString())
                {
                    Assert.AreEqual(type.ToString(), GetActionTypeElement(i).Text);
                    Assert.AreEqual(actionstatus.ToString(), GetActionStatusElement(i).Text);
                    Assert.AreEqual(departments == Enum.Departments.None ? " " : departments.ToString(),
                    GetActionDepartmentElement(i).Text);
                    return;
                }
            }
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            throw new NoSuchElementException($"Not found with'{title}'");
        }
    }
```

Because the id’s only had a difference in numbers (e.g. 0,1,2) I was able to use integer

Department:
//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_CPH_CPH_ActionsOverviewControl1_RadGridActions_ctl00__0"]/td[5]
//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_CPH_CPH_ActionsOverviewControl1_RadGridActions_ctl00__1"]/td[5]
//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_CPH_CPH_ActionsOverviewControl1_RadGridActions_ctl00__2"]/td[5]

Status:
//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_CPH_CPH_ActionsOverviewControl1_RadGridActions_ctl00__0"]/td[2]
//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_CPH_CPH_ActionsOverviewControl1_RadGridActions_ctl00__1"]/td[2]
//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_CPH_CPH_ActionsOverviewControl1_RadGridActions_ctl00__2"]/td[2]

Title:
//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_CPH_CPH_ActionsOverviewControl1_RadGridActions_ctl00__0"]/td[9]
//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_CPH_CPH_ActionsOverviewControl1_RadGridActions_ctl00__1"]/td[9]
//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_CPH_CPH_ActionsOverviewControl1_RadGridActions_ctl00__2"]/td[9]

Now I want to use a try catch that finds a button based on the same way of working but the id of this button is as follow:
//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_CPH_CPH_ActionsOverviewControl1_RadGridActions_ctl00_ctl04_ButtonClose"]
//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_CPH_CPH_ActionsOverviewControl1_RadGridActions_ctl00_ctl06_ButtonClose"]
//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_CPH_CPH_ActionsOverviewControl1_RadGridActions_ctl00_ctl08_ButtonClose"]
//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_CPH_CPH_ActionsOverviewControl1_RadGridActions_ctl00_ctl10_ButtonClose"]
//*[@id="ctl00_ctl00_CPH_CPH_ActionsOverviewControl1_RadGridActions_ctl00_ctl12_ButtonClose"]

As you can see it starts at ctl04 and continues in steps of two.

I cannot figure out how to design my private webelement. I tried:

```
private IWebElement GetActionCloseButtonElement(int actionRowNumber)
    {
        var xpath = $"//tr[@id = 'ctl00_ctl00_CPH_CPH_ActionsOverviewControl1_RadGridActions_ctl00_{actionRowNumber}_ButtonClose']";
        return BrowserFactory.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath));
    }
```

But that doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

actionRowNumber should be 04, 06, 08, 10, 12 as from the xpath.

```
private IWebElement GetActionCloseButtonElement(int actionRowNumber)
{
return BrowserFactory.Driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//tr[@id = 'ctl00_ctl00_CPH_CPH_ActionsOverviewControl1_RadGridActions_ctl00_ctl"+ actionRowNumber +"_ButtonClose']"));
}
```

Comment: I get NoSuchElementException

Comment: try this swap at the xapth to    "//*[@id =  at the begining swap tr with * and see what happens keep the rest the same

Comment: Where do i put the 'actionRowNumber = 04, 06, 08, 10, 12'?

Comment: that was just an example of what the row numbers should be, in relation to your xpath

Comment: I think the problem is with my try catch. Because the gettitleelement has i = 0 and then I say click on button where i = 0. But the buttons have compleet different numbers:
ctl04_ButtonClose 
ctl06_ButtonClose

and so on

Comment: Does liook like your throwing an exception no matter what

Comment: It itterates 4 times then throws an exception, even if succeeded